# R - function t() in as.data.frame()

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question about R programming.

I got a example code. this is

```
x <- read.table("example.txt", sep="=", header=F, nrows=6, fill=T)  
x <-x[,c(1:2)] 
x_t <- as.data.frame(t(x1)) 
names(x_t) <- c("ID", "URL", "SIZE", "DATE", "TIME", "DATASET") 
x_t <- x_t[c(2),] 
rownames(x_t) <- NULL
```

so, I changed source code. my source code is,

```
file <- list.files("./dataSet") 

for(i in 1:length(file)){
  location[i] = paste("./dataSet/", file[i], sep="")
}

for(i in 1:1000){
  assign(paste("a", i, sep=""), read.table(location[i], sep="=", header=F, nrow=6, fill=TRUE))
  assign(paste("a", i), paste("a", i, "[,c(1:2)]"))
  **assign(paste("a", i, "_t", sep=""), as.data.frame(t(paste("a", i, sep=""))))**
  assign(paste("a", i, "_t"), paste("a", i, "[c(2),]"))
}
```

---

result of a1 is:
[image]

---

result of a1_t is:

[image]

---

but, result of example is:

[image]

---

I want get same result with example code.

I think part of "** **" is problem.

and if i add

```
assign(rownames(paste("a", i, "_t")), NULL)
```

how do i write source code?

if you know solution, help me please.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.frame(
  V1 = c("ID", "URL", "SIZE", "DATE", "TIME", "DATASET"),
  V2 = c("A0001", "htttp://long.url", "54258", "27/06/02", "16:47:17", "Commercial Banks"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE # use stringsAsFactors = FALSE in your `read.table()` call as well
) -> xdf

xdf
##        V1               V2
## 1      ID            A0001
## 2     URL htttp://long.url
## 3    SIZE            54258
## 4    DATE         27/06/02
## 5    TIME         16:47:17
## 6 DATASET Commercial Banks

docxtractr::assign_colnames(
  as.data.frame(
    t(xdf),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  ),
1)
##      ID              URL  SIZE     DATE     TIME          DATASET
## 1 A0001 htttp://long.url 54258 27/06/02 16:47:17 Commercial Banks
```

Comment: thank you!   can i ask one more question?  i wanna add V1, V2, V3, ... V6 on the ID, URL, SIZE, .... DATASET.  how can i solve that? and what is the '1' of the left side?

Comment: sorry,  i have to use variable like " assign(paste("a", i, "_t", sep=""), docxtractr::assign_colnames(
  as.data.frame(
    t(paste("a", i, sep="")),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  ), 1)) "   can you help me one more?